# How to bind code when you delete a row with Grid?

Tags: safecracker, ee3, grid

I'm trying to figure out how to run some jquery after you click trash can icon to delete a row in grid. I have ajax code I have to run if you delete a row. EE has code in there that probably has preventDefault() which is stopping my code from triggering.

This is inside a channel form field on frontend.  I can't seem to bind anything to that delete row icon

Comment: `preventDefault()` wouldn't stop a trigger hook on click created using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution... I changed the selector and that seemed to do the trick.  For some reason the selector I was using had too much binded but this new selector worked.  I also changed $('body') to $(document) and that worked.

final code that worked was

$(document).on('click', 'ul.toolbar li.remove a', function(){